# Determine image saturation level with PHP & Imagick

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, imagick

I want to use PHP & Imagemagick to determine the saturation level of an image.  I know how to convert it an HSL colorspace, but I'll be damned if I can figure out how to read the saturation level.

Comment: [Have you checked the documentation?](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#modulate)

Comment: Have you read my question?  I don't want to use imagemagick & `convert` on the command line - I want to use PHP & Imagemagick.  I don't want to SET the saturation (I know how to do that with the function you linked), I want to GET the saturation.

Comment: The function you want is getimagechannelstatistics. In HSL space the 2nd channel will be saturation - http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagechannelstatistics.php

Comment: @Danack - thanks.  I wasn't able to find any documentation that stated which channel from that function was saturation.  Make your comment an answer and I'll accept it.